# Synchronous vs Asynchronous languages

Tags: programming-languages, asynchronous, synchronous

In last 1 year I was working on Java and flex. While coding flex, most of my code parts went for a toss since its asynchronous. It made me to think about the real advantages and disadvantages of synchronous executing languages vs asynchronously executing ones.

What are the areas where they are stronger compared to other and what are the areas they falls?

Comment: How can a language be asynchronous?

Comment: @NSD - what he means is that flex never blocks - all operations that could be blocking on other platforms are implemented asynchonously.

Comment: Do you have a definition for "synchronous executing language"? Or are you simply interpreting the event-driven nature of Flex (which is also found in almost every other GUI API, including Java's) as "asynchronous"?

Comment: @kdgregory- I cant understand why you simply changed the execution mechanism of flex by the name event driven nature of flex. Its quite hard for me to digest since this is the first language that I am playing with which have this kind of behavior. Other languages like c and all will wait for the called method to complete to go to next line. But in this it does not. But flex execute them in threads which makes execution faster(I think). But they are also having event listeners which needs a listener keeps running that eats up CPU cycles -Am I correct? So what is the Advantage?

Comment: I didn't think Flex was a language. I guess this is an areas I falls.

Comment: C can have asynchronous methods, as can most languages.  Maybe you are confusing languages with frameworks?

Comment: @Azeem.Butt Wierd example, javascript. Force async style by 'single thread'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've spent most of the last year coding in Silverlight, which means I've spent a good deal of time thinking through (and fighting with) the same issues you're describing.

In brief, as other folks have pointed out, the real strength to the asynchronous model is its ability to create robust systems that interoperate well with the real world.  Nobody could realistically use a Silverlight (or Flash) application if the UI thread came to a halt every time it took a few seconds for a web service call to return.

The biggest downside is that it the resulting code is complex and difficult to troubleshoot.  Things like error handling are a PITA, but the most annoying stuff I've had to deal with is coordinating responses from multiple asynchronous calls.  If, say, you need information from call A before making call B, and you need information from call B before making call C (and so forth), the resulting code looks really unpleasant, and is susceptible to all sorts of weird side-effects.  There are techniques for making all this stuff work, and even reasonably clean, but if you're coming from the synchronous world (as I was), it's a significant learning curve.  (And it doesn't help that Microsoft pushes events as the way to deal with WCF calls when callbacks, in my opinion, are much cleaner and less susceptible to the sort of weird side-effects I was talking about.)

(And yes, other folks are correct in saying that it's not the language that's asynchronous so much as that particular frameworks require constructing your code in an asynchronous manner -- but I get what you mean.)

Update 2014.09.23 -

I've done a lot more work with a variety of asynchronous frameworks since I wrote the answer above (as has probably everybody else who's done any web coding), and thought I'd add a few additional random notes:

- If you're using a language like C# or F# that has first-class asynchronous support, a lot of this gets a whole lot easier, at least, once you wrap your head around the weird `async`/`await` patterns. Being able to loop easily around asynchronous calls, and wrap the whole thing with a simple `try/catch`, is amazing if you've ever had to do it the old way.
- If you're not using a language with first-class async support, start using whatever `promise` or `future` or `task` support that the language does provide (e.g., JQuery's `$.Deferred()`, or Angular's `$q.defer()`. Those are a lot cleaner and provide better structure than what you typically get with callbacks.
- Asynchronous code is critical for writing scalable server-side systems. One of the biggest issues with making a typical web server scale well is that it starts running out of threads, at least, it does if it dedicates a thread to reach incoming request. If that thread stalls, because it's waiting for a long-running synchronous call to finish, it's completely unavailable for helping out with anything else. Much better is to make your web server code async, so that when you're waiting on a DB call to return, that thread can go service half a dozen other requests while the DB is going and doing whatever DB's do. At this point, for highly scalable systems, async is the only game in town. (Just ask any Node aficionado.)

Comment: Is there any practices for writing applications in event driven framework?

Comment: Let's just say that lambda expressions are your new best friend :-).  Apart from that, the I think the patterns and practices will largely vary from framework to framework, depending on the constraints that they place on you.  For instance, in the Silverlight world, I've found that it helps dramatically to wrap the event-driven pattern that Microsoft provides with a callback-oriented pattern (and I usually implement the callback as a lambda expression).  This makes it dramatically easier to follow the application logic.  I haven't done enough Flex to know what's appropriate there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation Sir. I am also coming from sync world and constantly thought how dirty async code is. 
I will take your advice and get into Node. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(Leaving aside the semantics level discussion i.e. "sync/async language")

A "framework" built on a "language" (whatever it is) should be able to handle such cases (sync/async programme flow) in order to be useful (read: $ wise).

Asynchronous idioms are appropriate at every scale.

At large scale, asynchronous techniques help build reliable systems because the real world is anyhow asynchronous in nature. In other words, one needs to think in "asynchronous thoughts" to cope with real-life situations such as failures, losses, delays etc.

Even on a smaller scale (e.g. GUI application), events (such as "mouse clicks") tend to be "asynchronous". Of course they are "serialized" at some point (in order to be processable by an application running some software) but it doesn't change the fact that events (probably) occurred 
 "asynchronously" with regards to the flow of the programme in question.

Comment: True if you think multiple test cases in parallel. But as far as I can think, they will only help for test cases. In real life and all the "next what" is purely depends on "what is happening now" or result of that. So how can be asynchronous become an achievement?

Comment: @Umesh: the "what is happening now" is a "sandbox" that is created by artificially "serialization" events. It is a question of "reference frame" (as we would call it in physics).  As for "how can be asynchronous become an achievement", I must say I am not following you.  Would you please care to explain?

Comment: Your explanation made me clear. Please forget my question. Thanks

Comment: @Umesh: Would you really want the menu bars on your web browser to be unresponsive whenever your browser is making a network request?  There are plenty of places where things can happen without knowing the result of some random call.

Comment: @tloach - I agree. But just a thought.. asynchronous approach solves the question that you asked. But for achieving functionality that need to be in synchronous, we are doing events and all in asynchronous language (flex/action script). So my question for jidupont was what is the rate of occurrence for synchronous events compared to asynchronous events. Means in which method a programming language needs to be base on and give the other one as an option that you can implement using it.(I think I am clear)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not about the language, but about the framework.

Counter-case in point:

When writing 'Classic Mac' (MacOS 9 and before) applications in C (a 'synchronous' language if there ever was one), you don't have preemptive multithreading, so all potentially blocking system calls have an async counterpart, where you fill a block of data with parameters including a callback function.  Then you do the system call (which would return immediately), and your callback would be called asynchronously (in what's called 'interrupt level').  It wasn't uncommon that a callback would do another async system call, creating a long background thread that ran asynchronously with the main one.

Comment: Does it really means a performance improvement by running things parallel and utilizing the hardware. But what is the cost of listening to the callbacks from parent thread. Do they have better side?

Comment: @Umesh: You don't listen for callbacks from another thread, the thread calls the callback directly.  The overhead is the same as any other function call.